# package android.content does not exist

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to write android codes without using android studio, and I have followed two tutorials to achieve this:
https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-setup-android-sdk-without-android-studio-6d60d0f2812a
https://authmane512.medium.com/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676
However, as I tried to build, I encountered a lot of errors stating android.<package> does not exist. How do I get the packages? Should I install them somewhere, or how do I tell the compiler to use them?

My build command:

```
javac -d obj -classpath src -sourcepath ../android/platforms/android-32/android.jar ./src/com/example/projectname/*.java
```

Errors:

> ./src/com/example/projectname/GamePanel.java:3: error: package
> android.content does not exist

> ./src/com/example/projectname/GamePanel.java:4: error: package
> android.graphics does not exist

> ./src/com/example/projectname/GamePanel.java:5: error: package
> android.view does not exist

> ./src/com/example/projectname/GamePanel.java:6: error: package
> android.view does not exist

> ./src/com/example/projectname/GamePanel.java:8: error: package
> androidx.annotation does not exist

I've been researching, but most of the answers seem to require the usage of android studio itself. However, that's what I've been avoiding because it takes forever for android studio to run.

Comment: It looks like you have the `-classpath` and `-sourcepath` options mixed up. I recommend taking a read of the manual page for the `javac` command.  Then compare what it says with the command line that you used.

Comment: *"However, that's what I've been avoiding because it takes forever for android studio to run."* - Only on a machine that it too small; e.g. no enough RAM.  Check the recommended hardware specs ... and if your machine meets the specs you should be fine.  (Many things you read on the internet are exaggerations.)

Comment: I did a little research and realized that I did mix up `-classpath` and `-sourcepath`, thank you!
I did initially run Android Studio on my machine, but it's far too slow for my standards. I only have about 3 hrs per day to code for my private project, so...